# I am getting compilation error in if -else program in python .The code is written in Python 3, can anyone help me

Tags: python, if-statement

```
  n = int(input().strip())
  if N % 2 != 0:
    print "Weird"
else:
    if N >= 2 and N <= 5:
        print "Not Weird"
    elif N >= 6 and N <= 20:
        print "Weird"
    elif N > 20:
        print "Not Weird"
##if else problem in python 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the print statement without paranthesis, it seems the code you are showing is python2, partially compatible with python3.

- Either execute it with python2 interpreter (deprecated)
- Or change a few stuffs to get it compliant to python3.

Besides, as mentionned, the take care of the case sensitivity for symbols like variables and functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you named you variable n. But you use it with a capital N. Python is case-sensitive so you have to keep everything the same.